# Python 3.7.1 Crashes When I Open File On Mac OS X

Tags: macos, crash, python3

When I open a python file with IDLE 3.7.1, it crashes after a few seconds. Sometimes, if I run the script, it would not crash. Even if I don't do anything, it crashes.

I'm not sure what is causing the crash. Any help or suggest would be appreciated.

```
    Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff78a6cb66 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c37080 pthread_kill + 333
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff789c81ae abort + 127
3   QtCore                          0x0000000105b4d8a9 0x105b36000 + 96425
4   QtCore                          0x0000000105b4f08f QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const + 213
5   QtCore.so                       0x00000001059a35fc pyqt5_err_print() + 812
6   QtCore.so                       0x00000001059a9297 PyQtSlotProxy::unislot(void**) + 103
7   QtCore.so                       0x00000001059a91fa PyQtSlotProxy::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) + 58
8   QtCore                          0x0000000105d457d6 QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) + 2230
9   QtWidgets                       0x0000000106f5a12f 0x106e60000 + 1024303
10  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106f59fc2 0x106e60000 + 1023938
11  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106f5b22f QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) + 271
12  QtWidgets.so                    0x0000000106a22648 sipQPushButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) + 120
13  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106eaa050 QWidget::event(QEvent*) + 496
14  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106f5ad91 QAbstractButton::event(QEvent*) + 145
15  QtWidgets.so                    0x0000000106a22f60 sipQPushButton::event(QEvent*) + 192
16  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106e6fd32 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 306
17  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106e72b8d QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 7357
18  QtWidgets.so                    0x0000000106a3f7ca sipQApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 234
19  QtCore                          0x0000000105d1485f QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) + 159
20  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106e70660 QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool) + 896
21  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106eca180 0x106e60000 + 434560
22  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106ec8e60 0x106e60000 + 429664
23  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106e6fd32 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 306
24  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106e7110d QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 573
25  QtWidgets.so                    0x0000000106a3f7ca sipQApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 234
26  QtCore                          0x0000000105d1485f QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) + 159
27  QtGui                           0x0000000106418094 QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::MouseEvent*) + 3412
28  QtGui                           0x00000001063ffd4b QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 155
29  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x000000010a1b3af1 QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::postedEventsSourceCallback(void*) + 33
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff50ae4a11 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff50b9e42c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 108
32  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff50ac7470 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
33  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff50ac68ed __CFRunLoopRun + 1293
34  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff50ac6153 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
35  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4fdb0d96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
36  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4fdb0a0f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 366
37  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4fdb0884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4e061a73 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
39  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4e7f7e34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
40  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4e056885 -[NSApplication run] + 764
41  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x000000010a1b28ed QCocoaEventDispatcher::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 2397
42  QtCore                          0x0000000105d103b2 QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 418
43  QtCore                          0x0000000105d14f72 QCoreApplication::exec() + 402
44  QtWidgets.so                    0x0000000106b2f662 meth_QApplication_exec_(_object*, _object*) + 82
45  org.python.python               0x00000001050c361c _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 668
46  org.python.python               0x00000001050c2a9a _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords + 42
47  org.python.python               0x0000000105182424 call_function + 724
48  org.python.python               0x000000010517f406 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25190
49  org.python.python               0x0000000105182f56 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2422
50  org.python.python               0x00000001051790c4 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
51  org.python.python               0x00000001051b6591 PyRun_FileExFlags + 209
52  org.python.python               0x00000001051b5e0a PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 890
53  org.python.python               0x00000001051d419b pymain_main + 6827
54  org.python.python               0x00000001051d46ea _Py_UnixMain + 58
55  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff7891c015 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff78a6d28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c34009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c33be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff78a6320a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff78a62724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff50ac7785 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff50ac6ad7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff50ac6153 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4e19efc4 _NSEventThread + 184
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c34661 _pthread_body + 340
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c3450d _pthread_start + 377
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c33bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff78a6cd82 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff789e7724 nanosleep + 199
2   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib              0x000000010743261c SDL_Delay + 84
3   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib              0x000000010743269a RunTimer + 48
4   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib              0x000000010740bf8d SDL_RunThread + 53
5   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib              0x000000010742e764 RunThread + 9
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c34661 _pthread_body + 340
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c3450d _pthread_start + 377
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c33bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.audio.IOThread.client
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff78a6320a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff78a62724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x00007fff5051f87a HALB_MachPort::SendMessageWithReply(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, mach_msg_header_t*, bool, unsigned int) + 124
3   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x00007fff5051f7ed HALB_MachPort::SendSimpleMessageWithSimpleReply(unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int&, bool, unsigned int) + 45
4   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x00007fff5051c859 HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop() + 977
5   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x00007fff5051c2bc HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOThreadEntry(void*) + 128
6   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x00007fff5051bffe HALB_IOThread::Entry(void*) + 72
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c34661 _pthread_body + 340
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c3450d _pthread_start + 377
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c33bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff78a6d28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c3420e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c33be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff78a6d28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c34009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c33be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff78a6d28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c3420e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff78c33be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fffb141f380  rcx: 0x00007ffeeab619b8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffeeab619f0  rsp: 0x00007ffeeab619b8
   r8: 0x00007fffb13fe048   r9: 0x0000000000000040  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000000307  r13: 0x00007fd98f6b6500  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x000000000000002d
  rip: 0x00007fff78a6cb66  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fffb13fc168

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

[Code Share Link for Crash Log](https://codeshare.io/5wYbRp)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the error log (formatted as code) as links to external site are not guaranteed to always be available and questions should be self contained.

Comment: @DavidPostill What should I do if the text length exceeds the limit?

Comment: Just include the important parts.